# how can i increase the button size in css?

Tags: css, button

when I am increasing the font size of the button, it shows no response whatsoever why is it stuck in this condition please explain.

P.S. I just want to clarify that this code is already worked before but now it isn't working there is some technical problem with this code.

code-
.buttons{

```
     margin-top: 444px;
     padding: 9px 14px;
     border-radius: 22px;
     color: white;
     /* background-color: dodgerblue;*/
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 21px;    
     margin: 0 3px;
     cursor: pointer;
     }
```

it is showing the background color in the whole tab rather than just showing it in the button and vice versa.

Comment: Hi Satyam, I checked you snippet and its working fine.
Check fiddle below:
https://jsfiddle.net/niks1020/9puLacqo/

If I update the font-size attribute, but font and button size gets increased.

Comment: Please edit your post and include a [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the relevant HTML part as the problem might be somewhere else in the original code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Your css code works properly for me. may be you can check your class name in both css and html.

```css
.buttons{
     margin-top: 444px;
     padding: 9px 14px;
     border-radius: 22px;
     color: white;
     background-color: dodgerblue;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 23px;    
     margin: 0 3px;
     cursor: pointer;
     }
```

```html
<button class="buttons" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```